# How to store information at each iteration of nested loops?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a dictionary of values, and I need to store multiple levels of information to later be exported to excel. I can't figure out how to store the value at each iteration; I've tried multiple approaches but I'm putting here the approach that has gotten me the closest.

```
thisdict =  {            # Values in this dictionary will change, but key's will always be the same
  "Bob": [6,9,22,31,4],
  "Sam": [55,12,32,13,4],
  "Jeff": [53,1,52,37,4],
  "Tim": [5,41,2,31,4,5],
  "Lisa": [45,1,32,34,54,56]
}

allStats = {}           # Store final product in Dictionary    
tempStats = {}          # Store stats for each digit
     
for name, numbers in thisdict.items():
    
    for iteration, digit in enumerate(numbers):
        
        stats = [digit+3,digit-3] # List(or np.array) of various stats, store stats each iteration 
        tempStats[iteration] = stats
        
    allStats[name] = tempStats
```

This gets me close; here `tempStats` seems to store the stats at each iteration correctly. However, `allStats` doesn't store the `tempStats` dictionary when iterating over each name. Instead, it stores one iteration of `tempStats`.

If possible, I'd also like to accomplish this with DataFrames, both to learn how to manipulate them, and because I'm more familiar with how to output that information to excel. But beggers can't be choosers.

Comment: If I understand what you want to accomplish correctly, the line tempStats = {} should be inside the outer for loop. Otherwise, you are overwriting the values of `tempStats` at each loop iteration.

Comment: ...yeah that did the trick :|